# Pandas Series Chaining: Filter on boolean value

Tags: pandas, chaining

How can I filter a pandas series based on boolean values?

Currently I have:

```
s.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x, myparam).where(lambda x: x).dropna()
```

What I want is only keep entries where `myfunc` returns true.`myfunc` is complex function using 3rd party code and operates only on individual elements.

How can i make this more understandable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
mask = s.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x, myparam))
print (s[mask])
```

If also is changed index values in `mask` filter by 1d array:

```
#pandas 0.24+
print (s[mask.to_numpy()])

#pandas below
print (s[mask.values])
```

EDIT:

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3])

def myfunc(x, n):
    return x > n

myparam = 1
a = s[s.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x, myparam))]
print (a)
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Solution with [callable](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#selection-by-callable) is possible, but a bit overcomplicated in my opinion:

```
a = s.loc[lambda s: s.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x, myparam))]
print (a)
1    2
2    3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: So it's not possible with chaining in an easier way that i did?

Answer (score 5):

You can understand it with below given sample code

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series([1,12,15,3,5,3,6,9,10,5])
print(data)

# filter data based on a condition keep only rows which are multiple of 3
filter_cond = data.apply(lambda x:x%3==0)
print(filter_cond)
filter_data = data[filter_cond]
print(filter_data)
```

This code is about to filter the series data which are of the multiples of 3. To do that, we just put the filter condition and apply it on the series data. You can verify it with below generated output.

**The sample series data:**

```
0     1
1    12
2    15
3     3
4     5
5     3
6     6
7     9
8    10
9     5
dtype: int64
```

**The conditional filter output:**

```
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
4    False
5     True
6     True
7     True
8    False
9    False
dtype: bool
```

**The final required filter data:**

```
1    12
2    15
3     3
5     3
6     6
7     9
dtype: int64
```

Hope, this helps you to understand that how we can apply conditional filters on the series data.

Comment: Sorry, what is diifference between my solution and your? Why is posted 1 hour later?